# Broken flutter after downgrade

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, gradle

After downgrading my flutter version, I can't launch a single app.

First I had to solve some package conflict, and after that I couldn't build any app.

This is the message when I try to run flutter run :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:107)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.<clinit>(ReflectionCache.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:86) 
        at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)      
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.getDefaultMetaClass(GroovyObjectSupport.java:59)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.<init>(DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.<init>(DefaultConvention.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ExtensibleDynamicObject.<init>(ExtensibleDynamicObject.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.MixInExtensibleDynamicObject.<init>(MixInExtensibleDynamicObject.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated.getAsDynamicObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsFactory.createSettings(SettingsFactory.java:58)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:102)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:45)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:59)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:42)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:197)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:141)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:130)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)       
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)   
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
```

This is also the output of my flutter doctor -v :

```
[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19041.868], locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (1 year, 2 months ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

 
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\lescavia\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-15.0.0.36-hotspot\bin\java.exe
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.     

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\lescavia\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I tried to reinstall everything (reclone projet, vscode, android studio, flutter sdk) but nothings changed.

I also tried, flutter clean and flutter pub cache repair but the problem is still there.

Hope someone can help me please !

Edit : after I modified distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties, I now have this error

```
Compiler message:
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-2.1.9+1/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:235:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'clipBehavior'.
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:3187:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  Stack({
  ^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.                                                                  
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: AFAICR this has something to do with JDK path.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how can I fix that ? I looked my java environment variable but nothing seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just reverted my downgrade by removing my flutter sdk and replacing it with the one that I used before downgrading. I guess my package weren't compatible with this Flutter version.

Thanks for the help @RukshanJS appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Your new error log shows that the package "percent_indicator" needs an upgrade.

In your `pubspec.yaml` file put the latest version of it. (3.0.1 at the time of writing this)

```
dependencies:
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
```

After that, save your `pubspec.yaml` to get the packages. If needed, restart VS Code (or your IDE), then rebuild the app.

Comment: After I update my package version, I have a new error message that says


`Because my_app depends on percent_indicator >=3.0.1 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because my_app depends on percent_indicator >=3.0.1 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)`

Should I also update my sdk version ?

Comment: Yep, that should fix it now. This is a minor error.

Comment: And how can I update it ? Should I download a other sdk on the flutter website and change my environment variable ?

Comment: In the `pubspec.yaml` (towards the top of the file), you can edit as `environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`, and save it again.

Comment: Still got an error... Thanks a lot for the help 
`The current Dart SDK version is 2.7.0.

Because my_app requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.`

Comment: For this, I'm not sure, you need to install Dart SDK 2.12.0 at least (I have 2.12.2, and Flutter 2.0.4), but don't know whether it supports your current Flutter version. Maybe someone can help confirm this.